# Can I return a function the same way as a getter does?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am writing a wrapper for console.log() so that I have some control over when it runs.

I can get it to work when I use a getter but I want to use a normal function so that I can pass some args.

I want it to function the same as using a getter as it prints the correct class and line number in the console.

When I use a getter the correct message and class name and line number is output to the console:

```
get info() {
        return console.info.bind(console);
}
```

called by:

```
this.logger.info('this is a log');
```

results in console:

> this is a log

When I use a function nothing gets output to the console

```
public info() {
        return console.info.bind(console);
}
```

called by:

```
this.logger.info('this is a log');
```

results in blank console:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a function it is simply returning the function reference bound with the `this` reference` you passed, when you call it the first time.

So you need to invoke the returned function object again with the parameter. As an example I have done the same in in an es6  class below:

```js
class Test{
  info() {
     return console.info.bind(console);
  }
}
let test = new Test();
test.info()("test");
```

If this needs to be done in a single step we can use either `call` or `apply` instead of bind. `call` or `apply` calls the function immediately unlike bind which will just just bind the `this` reference and return the bound function.

For using `call`:

```
info(){
   return console.info.call(console, ...arguments);
}
```

and `apply`:

```
info(){
   return console.info.apply(console, arguments);
 }
```

On the other hand, when you use a *getter*, accessing a property like `info` will cause the getter to be invoked and the function reference to be returned which you are invoking immediately.

```js
class Test{
  get info() {
      return console.info.bind(console);
  }
}
let test = new Test();
test.info("test");
```

```
test.info -> returns the function reference
test.info("test") -> invokes the returned reference;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
public info() {
  return console.info.apply(console, arguments)
}
```

This will do.